# PHP getaddrinfo issue

Tags: php, ip

I am getting the below warning everytime I try to access other server. But when I access again the below error is gone.

What I have tried:

```
 I have used host IP address instead of Host name but it still did not resolve.
```

When does this Occur

```
 1. When I try to use file_get_html(..);
 2. When I try to use ftp_connect(..);
```

Warning Message:

```
 file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

Comment: So what you have coded?

Comment: I am just trying to connect an external ftp using php... ftp_connect(). I am unable to connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Httpd should be allowed to connect outside. Check you selinux policy.

```
setsebool -P nis_enabled 1
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

L.E.: Provided you have root access to the linux console

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Restarting the Server solves the issue temporarily. But don't know about Permanent solution

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting the error in file_get_contents(), it means the file from which you are trying to get the content is not accessible.

```
file_get_contents($path_of_file);
```

Check the path properly and also the permission of the file.

Comment: The path and the file is accessible... I am unable to connect ftp at times as well. Also file_get_contents() works well sometimes